# file-type npm module returns null despite being called with buffer, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, file-upload, buffer

I'm developing a website where users can upload video files to be stored in MongoDB. Before the files get uploaded and stored, I would like to check and validate the mimetype of the file. I would like to do that with help of a npm module, I have tried without success with file-type.

Link to file-type npm module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type

I call the module with buffer of uploaded files (tested with mp4-files) but it returns null. Here is my code for the upload route:

```
'use strict';

const router = require('express').Router();
const VideoInfo = require('../../models/VideoInfo');
const VideoAmount = require('../../models/VideoAmount');
const path = require('path');
const Lib = require('../../lib/Lib');
const multer = require('multer');
const GridFsStorage = require('multer-gridfs-storage');
const fileType = require('file-type');

// Defines storage of files with validation
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: process.env.dbURL,
  file: (req, file) => {
    const data = [];

    req.on('data', chunk => {
      data.push(chunk);
    });

    req.on('end', () => {
      const buffer = Buffer.concat(data);
      const fType = fileType(buffer);

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (fType === null) {
          return reject(new Error('Unsupported file format'));
        }

        if (fType.mime !== 'video/mp4' ||
            fType.mime !== 'video/webm' ||
            fType.mime !== 'video/ogg') {
          return reject(new Error('Unsupported file format'));
        }

        if (!req.session.username) {
          return reject(new Error('Unauthorized file upload attempt'));
        }

        // changes the file name before storing
        const fileName =
          Lib.make.randomString() + path.extname(file.originalname);
        const fileInfo = {
          filename: fileName,
          bucketName: 'uploads'
        };
        resolve(fileInfo);
      });
    });
  }
});
const upload = multer({ storage });

router.route('/upload')

  .get((req, res) => {
    // renders upload form, not really relevant
  })

  .post(upload.single('video'), async (req, res) => {
    // file gets saved to DB with upload.single-function
  });

module.exports = router;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I wasn't getting the video file buffer.

What solved it was including busboy-body-parser in my app:

```
const busboyBodyParser = require('busboy-body-parser')

app.use(busboyBodyParser({
  limit: '120mb'
}))
```

Then I could get the buffer from the request:

```
const fileContent = req.files.video
const buffer = fileContent.data
```

Then I could get the file type of the file by calling file-type with the buffer.